# Hide or remove duplicated data from table HTML per object

Tags: html

I am getting some data from database with joins and it repeats values

it's basically like this.  The only value that is unique is ticket.

```
!  Reference  |  Localization  |  Ticket  |
|   M13000    |      MP1       |     1    |
|   M13000    |      MP1       |     2    |
|   M13000    |      MP1       |     3    |
|   M13000    |      MP1       |     4    |
|   M13000    |      MP2       |     7    |
|   M13000    |      MP2       |     8    |
|   M13000    |      MP2       |     9    |
|   M13001    |      MP1       |     11   |
|   M13001    |      MP1       |     12   |
|   M13001    |      MP1       |     13   |
|   M13002    |      MP4       |     15   |
|   M13002    |      MP4       |     16   |
```

when printing this data i was looking for the following output

```
!  Reference  |  Localization  |  Ticket  |
|   M13000    |      MP1       |     1    |
|             |                |     2    |
|             |                |     3    |
|             |                |     4    |
|             |      MP2       |     7    |
|             |                |     8    |
|             |                |     9    |
|   M13001    |      MP1       |     11   |
|             |                |     12   |
|             |                |     13   |
|   M13002    |      MP4       |     15   |
|             |                |     16   |
```

Basically there is a hierarchy,

References have Localizations and Localizations have Tickets.

I did this using C# and liq, through many cycles and mapped everything into objects. While the final result given was correct, however it hard to handle the layout on html after specially because one of my requirements is to maximize space per page so i split the table into 2 columns per page.

Pretty much this

```
  |  Reference   |  Localization   |   Ticket    |   |  Reference   |  Localization   |   Ticket    |
  |  Reference   |  Localization   |   Ticket    |   |  Reference   |  Localization   |   Ticket    |
  |  Reference   |  Localization   |   Ticket    |   |  Reference   |  Localization   |   Ticket    |
  |  Reference   |  Localization   |   Ticket    |   |  Reference   |  Localization   |   Ticket    |
  |  Reference   |  Localization   |   Ticket    |   |  Reference   |  Localization   |   Ticket    |
  |  Reference   |  Localization   |   Ticket    |   |  Reference   |  Localization   |   Ticket    |
```

So I thought it was much easier just to get all data in a list and handle the rest on the front end but i can't seem to figure out how to get the expected result.

Here is a code sample for testing

```html
 <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Reference</th>
                    <th>Localization</th>
                    <th>Ticket</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td> M13000 </td>
                    <td> MP1 </td>
                    <td> 1 </td>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> M13000 </td>
                    <td> MP1 </td>
                    <td> 2 </td>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> M13000 </td>
                    <td> MP2 </td>
                    <td> 3 </td>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> M13000 </td>
                    <td> MP2 </td>
                    <td> 4 </td>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> M13001 </td>
                    <td> MP2 </td>
                    <td> 5 </td>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> M13001 </td>
                    <td> MP3 </td>
                    <td> 6 </td>
                <tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you print the `Reference` and `Localization` values, compare them with the previous ones (that's you've stored) and only print them if they are different.

Not sure how you print that table in HTML, but what I described should be easy to achieve using any front-end language.

Here's a quick code snipped describing what I said:

```js
const fields = [
  ['M13000', 'MP1', 1 ],
  ['M13000', 'MP1', 2 ],
  ['M13000', 'MP1', 3 ],
  ['M13000', 'MP1', 4 ],
  ['M13000', 'MP2', 7 ],
  ['M13000', 'MP2', 8 ],
  ['M13000', 'MP2', 9 ],
  ['M13001', 'MP1', 11],
  ['M13001', 'MP1', 12],
  ['M13001', 'MP1', 13],
  ['M13002', 'MP4', 15],
  ['M13002', 'MP4', 16]
];

var div = document.getElementById('out');
var prevRef, prevLoc;
for(let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
  var output = '';
  output += "<p>";
  
  output += "<span>";
  output += fields[i][0] == prevRef ? " " : fields[i][0];
  output += "</span>|";
  
  output += "<span>";
  output += fields[i][1] == prevLoc ? " " : fields[i][1];
  output += "</span>|";
  
  output += "<span>";
  output += fields[i][2];
  output += "</span>";
  
  output += "</p>";
  div.innerHTML += output;
  
  prevRef = fields[i][0];
  prevLoc = fields[i][1];
}
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 10px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

If a localization also depends on a reference, then before printing a localization you should check if either a reference or a localization has changed (in my code, that would be `prevRef` and `prevLoc`).